# Website components not rendered in Mozilla and Opera

Tags: jquery, html, css, opera, mozilla

I am currently developing an one page website - www.deepakprabhakaran.com

It is written in HTML, CSS3, Jquery, Javascript.

The components are rendered as coded in Chrome and IE9. But it is not working in Mozilla and Opera.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please have patience while it loads...

Comment: The web components... the images that have been used as components are not displayed in the browser.

Comment: Can you be more specific please.

Answer (score 0):

That's three different rendering engines you are talking about. Multiple things could be wrong.

If you can send us a link it will be easier to see what is going on with your code.